# inserting current date values into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-insert

Can you insert current date via a function with an insert statement?

Should look something like this:

```
insert into table name 
values
(getdate(), getdate()-1)
,(getdate(), getdate()-1)
```

The above example may be vague but can this concept be done?

Comment: Can not you just check that yourself???

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri ..u dont know the situation some would have been still studying and have no access immediately to a system and thinking it theoretically

Comment: @JaydipJ, it look like it is `Microsoft Sql Server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can manipulate function directly

```
SELECT GETDATE()-1
```

But I will Suggets use `DATEADD` function

```
SELECT DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: ty.. theoretically what difference it will give using date add instead of direct function manipulation

Comment: `DATEADD` function internally manages what needs to add whether it is `DAY -->D`,`YEAR-->Y` or etc

Comment: one interesting thing that if you try `SELECT sysdatetime() - 1` this will give error

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes. You can use the results of function calls or calculations as arguments to a `values` clause of an `insert` statement.

Comment: thank you so it will be like ((select getdate()), (select getdate()-1))